# Backbone error when I pass a parameter on URL

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bakbone pushStat</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        var AppRouter  = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
               "/": "initHome",
               "home": "initHome",
               "projects/(:id)" : "initProject"
            }
        });
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('route:initHome' , function(){
                alert('initHome');
        });             
        app_router.on('route:initProject' , function(id){
                alert('Projet');    
        });

        $(document).on("click",".links",function(e) { 
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            var url =  lang + "/" + href;    
                page = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var param = $(this).attr("data-param");         
            if (typeof(param) == 'undefined') { param = ""; }  

            if(activepage != href && !main.hasClass("loadingPage")){    
                loader.show();  
                firstInit = false;
                activepage = href;
                res = app_router.navigate(url, true);
                getContent(page,param);
            }   
            return false;                           
        });
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/backbone_pushStat/"});
    })(jQuery);
</script>
   </head>
  <body>

<a href="home" class="foo">HOME</a><br/>
<a href="projects/toto" class="bar">TEST</a><br/>
    <div id="default">default</div>
    <div id="entrees">entrees</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

When I click the HOME link, it works very well.
But, I don’t know why, I get this error when I click the TEST link (firefox console).

SyntaxError: syntax error
    
        backbone-min.js (ligne 1)
        ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    })(jQuery);

Anything wrong with my code?
Please help.

Comment: Your router code looks wrong to me. I think you need to drop the parenthesis around :id. Not sure why that would result in a jQuery error though. Have you double checked your path to jQuery?

Comment: Thank's. But, I have already dropped the parenthese but still got the same error. And, all the paths are correct.

Comment: use $(function(){<code here>});

Comment: Thank you all. After a long test, it seems that my problem is with my htaccess and sorry if my question was not complete.